# BackboneJS / real time SPA - I don't get it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, backbone.js, signalr

I guess this will be my first closed question, but anyways:
I'm starting to develop real time single page application (because Web 3.7) with BackboneJS, ASP.NET MVC + SignalR server side for real time. Idea is this:

- App loads and initiates connection with server via SignalR.
- Upon navigating to some page, page setups SignalR client function which will handle incomming data and show it to user and tells server to send updates concerning that data, etc.

Now, server side is very clear to me. But not so much with client side - I do not understand anything. Official BackboneJS documentation is very basic and all other tutorials involve static models and REST api.

Wiews - all examples show that views live in "index.html" and get rendered with static models from REST api. I'll have atleast 7 views that are quite big with a lot of HTML and scripts, so keeping them in my "index.html" is not really an option. I've found nothing in regards to loading remote views and on my own I just figured calling jQuery's `load` function to load the view.

So having only static footer, header and menu, and loading views into #content DIV is not really SPA? This doesn't really from 'normal' web applications, except with jQuery + `load` I get to keep constant SignalR connection without really navigating away from "index.html".

Basicly I'm using Backbone just for routing and instead of full page requests I load partial views into main content div - am I engineering a some sort of abomination here, doing SPA totally wrong?

Any suggestions on how to do proper real time single page application?

Comment: I've found that DurandalJS (which uses Knockout as the MVC/MVVM layer, and doesn't specify a data-layer) works well for a SPA framework. It leverages RequireJS to make it easy to keep different view/models/controllers in separate resources (files) - all loading (if required) and resource management is automatic.

Comment: Anyway, with DurandalJS/Knockout, once you have the model defined (and used sensibly in a view), it's just a matter of updating the model and walking away - Breeze or SignalR or whatever custom access layer, it doesn't really matter. This same form of model updates is also how DurandalJS handles navigating between different (primary) views.

Comment: Will look into it more, seems about right so far for what I want - bindable Knockout objects which will get updated and view management.

Comment: Backbone is built for REST API so it doesn't have WebSocket treatment out of the box. There are plug-ins like https://github.com/logicalparadox/backbone.iobind and https://github.com/scttnlsn/backbone.io for Backbone + Socket.io; I think you can take similar approach and patch up Backbone with SignalR. But yes using framework that support 2-way binding out of the box like Knockout is probably more convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at KO + Durandal or if you want a smaller footprint library have a look at my little SPA lib for KO

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap.Demo

I have also made a Event aggregator proxy for SignalR it works very well with MVVM, once its configured it will automatically forward messages directly to the VM. Used like

```
TestViewModel = function () {
    signalR.eventAggregator.subscribe(MyApp.MyEvent, this.onMyEvent, this)
};

TestViewModel.prototype = {
    onMyEvent: function (message) {
        //act on my event
    }
};
```

wiki:

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

install using nuget

```
Install-Package SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using Backbone.js with something like [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/developers), a publisher subscriber concept?
 Here is a link that talks about how to make backbone,js work with it, [Backbone with PubNub](http://backbonetutorials.com/real-time-backbone-with-pubnub/). 
I'm looking to try it out soon with an SPA I have been working on as a pet project, where the main index.html is just a bunch of lines in the head section and then a call to a single js file with all the view templates, and backbone models and router. My aim is to have a model linked to a subscribed event from data that is published elsewhere. Not sure if this helps, but if you're interested, load up my site and then look at how it is built, pull it apart, maybe it is somewhat similar to how you are wanting to do things, [HydroSolar](http://www.paulalting.com/hydrosolar/hydrosolar.php). 
Presently, it still pulls data via the `this.myModel.fetch({async:true});` method on a periodic timed event, which works well, but like I mentioned, I'm keen to get it working with push technology like from PubNub.